# Ordenar Array utilizando una variable int desde otra clase

Tags: java, array

Actualmente soy nuevo en esto del java y tengo una pregunta sobre el ordenamiento de `arrays`. Tengo en una clase creada previamente este código.

```
public class Orden {

    int value;

    public Orden(){}

    public Orden(int value){

        this.value= value;
    }


    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

Luego tengo otra clase con lo siguiente:

```
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i;
        int j;
        int aux;
        Orden[] cosa=new Orden[10];

        cosa[1]= new Orden(5);
        cosa[2]= new Orden(9);
        cosa[3]= new Orden(55);
        cosa[4]= new Orden(88);
        cosa[5]= new Orden(44);
        cosa[6]= new Orden(66);
        cosa[7]= new Orden(33);
        cosa[8]= new Orden(33);
        cosa[9]= new Orden(44);
        cosa[0]= new Orden(88);


        for(i=0;i<(cosa.length-1);i++)
        {
            for(j=i+1;j<cosa.length;j++)
            {
                if(cosa[i].getValue()>cosa[j].getValue())
                {
                    aux=cosa[i].getValue();
                    cosa[i]=cosa[j];
                    cosa[j]=aux;
                }
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Pero tengo un error en la linea donde se indica `cosa[j]=aux;`. Según lo que he podido entender es porque estoy guardando un objeto en una variable `int`, pero no logro ver como guardar ese valor en la variable `aux`. Alguna recomendación?

Comment: Tu algoritmo de ordenamiento está correctamente implementado, solo que te equivocas en un pequeño detalle. Lo que debes intercambiar en el arreglo son los objetos no el valor de estos. Para solucionarlo solo debes declarar la variable `aux` de tipo `Orden` (así: `Orden aux;`) y modificar la linea dentro del for anidado donde le asignas valor a `aux`, dejándola así: `aux=cosa[i];`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estas utilizando `POO`, entonces para asignar el valor a un atributo deberías usar el `setter` definido en tu clase de esta forma, además el atributo debería ser `private` y no `public`.

```
private int value; // clase Orden

cosa[j].setValue(aux);
```

Pero al parecer intentas aplicar el [método burbuja](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordenamiento_de_burbuja) para ordenar elementos la cuál es incorrecta recomiendo leer la documentación sobre este método.  En lugar de declarar la variable temporal como entera *(int)* declararla del tipo clase `Orden` como mencionó @PabloLozano *(que en principio no tomé en cuenta)*

```
  int n = cosa.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++){
            if (cosa[j].getValue() > cosa[j+1].getValue()){
                Orden temp = cosa[j];
                cosa[j]= cosa[j+ 1];
                cosa[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

Con `Java8` es más sencillo Ordenar de la siguiente forma.  *(ascendente , si desea descendente cambie el orden p2.getValue() - p1.getValue() )*;

```
Arrays.asList(cosa).sort((p1, p2) -> p1.getValue() - p2.getValue());
```

Comment: Si te fijas, tu última línea ordena cambiando los objetos de lugar, mientras que tu implementación de burbuja intercambia sólo los atributos... creo que lo correcto es ordenar los objetos y no sus atributos (si tuviésemos un objeto con más de un atributo estaríamos haciendo algo más que ordenarlos)

Comment: @PabloLozano efectivamente , estaba mal el proceso de intercambio. Gracias.

Comment: corre perfecto! pero tengo otra duda! al momento de imprimir el ordenamiento utilizo un getValue

            System.out.println(cosa[i].getValue());
 

 pero me da este resultado

5
9
44
33
44
44
55
66
88

Según lo que tengo me esta colocando un 44 por un 33, por que sucede esto?

Comment: @JesusFiguera con cuál  de los dos métodos obtiene esto ? Con ambos debería funcionar correctamente.

Comment: Al momento de colocar la burbuja que indicaron arriba

Comment: @JesusFiguera con mi actualización? es raro para mi funciona correctamente, recuerde que tiene la segunda opción también :)

Answer (score 2):

Puedes definir `aux` de tipo Orden y simplemente hacer `aux=cosa[i];`, sería lo lógico para intercambiar los objetos de lugar en el array y no sus valores.